# Quarkus testing in Gradle - How to deal with test and native-test

Tags: testing, quarkus, quarkus-native

I have a Quarkus project that has both a `test` sources folder and a `native-test` folder. The guidance seems to be that I would have a lot of the same tests (specifically `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`s) in the `native-test` folder. Is there a way to specify to use the same source set in `test` as `native-test`?

It makes sense that one might want to have different tests in the other source-set, but it seems tedious to me to have to keep track of the same tests between the two source-sets. Is there a way to tell the `nativeTest` task to use the tests from the `test` source set? Is that what I want? Am I visuallizing the purposes of these tests correctly?

I have assumed I could set up in Gradle a bit of script to copy in relevant tests to the `native-test` directories when `testNative` runs but this feels quite hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nativeTest` task inherits from the `Test` task, so you should be able to configure it as the `test` task.

A problem you may face is that `gradle test` will run `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` with the default packaging (this may take time).
`gradle nativeTest` will run all tests event the `@QuarkusTest`.

Using `include` / `exclude` in task configuration may lead to what you want:

```
nativeTest {
  testClassesDirs = project.sourceSets.nativeTest.output.classesDirs
  include '**/it/*'
}

test {
  exclude '**/it/*'
}
```

`gradle test` will run all tests from `src/test/java` excepts tests in the `it` package.
`gradle nativeTest` will only run test from `src/test/java` located in the `it` package.

Comment: Yep, this turned into a deeper rabbit hole than I expected. Marking as accepted as it got me to where the quesion asked (though I modified the config a little). Related issue I just made: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23528